# Question regarding this particular random number generator in c

Tags: c

The following code is from the paper [Understanding Integer Overflow in C/C++](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eregehr/papers/overflow12.pdf)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define  IA  1103515245u
#define  IC  12346u
#define  IM  2147483648u

static  unsigned  int  c_rand = 0;

/*  Creates  a  random  integer  [0... imax] (inclusive ) */

int  my_irand (int  imax) {
  int  ival;

  /*  c_rand  = (c_rand  * IA + IC) % IM; */
  c_rand =  c_rand * IA + IC;//  Use  overflow  to  wrap
  ival = c_rand & (IM - 1);/*  Modulus  */
  ival = (int) (( float) ival * (float) (imax + 0.999)/ (float) IM);

  return  ival;

}

int main(void)
{
  int n = 100;

  printf("1: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("2: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("3: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("4: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("5: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("6: %d\n", my_irand(n));
  printf("7: %d\n", my_irand(n));

  return 0;
}
```

These are the questions that I have regarding this code snippet.

1. What are the reasons behind assigning IA, IC, and IM to their respective values?
   For IM, the largest integer value in C is 2147483647. So IM is just INT_MAX+1.
   Therefore IM may stand for Integer Maximum. I don't know. I am just guessing.
   However, I still don't understand what are IA and IC.
2. What is this formula, c_rand  = (c_rand  * IA + IC) % IM?
3. Why does ival need to be multiplied by (imax + 0.999)?

Basically, I just don't understand the whole logic of the code. Also, I notice the first value
generated is always zero, and this code always produces the same set of random numbers. I guess
if you want the result to be different every time you run the code, you need to modify it by utilizing time_t from time.h library.

Btw, any idea on how this code works will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a [linear congruential generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). The wikipedia article explains the A, C, and M constants.

Comment: Well, that helps. At least I have a pointer to follow.